# Get Specific Attribute of Text File

Tags: python, text, python-3.x

So I have a text file full of information in the following format:

```
|NAME|70|AST|TYPE|LOCATION|3||MNUM_1|NUM_2|DESCRIPTION|
```

And my code searches the text file for the NAME attribute and then returns all the information excluding the split character '|'. Here is my code:

```
    with open('TEXT.txt') as fd:
    input=[x.strip('|').split('|') for x in fd.readlines()]
    to_search={x[0]:x for x in input}
    print('\n'.join(to_search[name]))
```

Is there a way to edit my code so I can search the text file for the name attribute and pick which attribute I want returned and just return that attribute?

Comment: Is this *really* a different question than http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15593844/extracting-data-from-a-text-file-with-python ?

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use `csv` package for this type of data files, but in the existing code you can do this:

```
columns = ['NAME', '70', 'AST', 'TYPE', 'LOCATION', '3', 'SOMETHING', 'MNUM_1', 'NUM_2', 'DESCRIPTION']
return to_search[requested_name][columns.index(requested_column)]
```

Comment: Could I still do this if each attribute varies for each entry?

Comment: @user1985351 Yes, Why not?

Answer (score 0):

What about having the first line being the name of the fields, and then you can do something like this:

```
search_key = 'NAME'
search_query = 'foo'

with open('TEXT.txt') as fin:
    keys = fin.readline().strip('|').split('|')
    for line in fin:
        columns = line.strip().strip('|').split('|')
        obj = dict(zip(keys, columns))
        if obj[search_key] == search_query:
            ...
```

A lot of csv files follow this convention (of having the columns named in the first row) for exactly this reason.